# How to print barcode in Reports

Tags: acumatica

can someone please guide me how we can print barcodes which upon scan should read the number hookup to it. we have tried with code39 which prints the barcode but scanner is not identifying the number hookup up to it, we also tried with code128 which show barcode with red cross lines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't scan, the problem is within the scanner not with the barcode. Scanners come with configuration procedures so you can configure the code the scanner will use.

In doubt I'd recommend to go with Code 128 as most scanner support both 39/128 and 128 has support for more special characters like '*'.

To use Acumatica report designer to generate the barcodes.

1. Place a PictureBox control in the report
2. Set Barcode->Source property to Barcode
3. Use Barcode->BarcodeType to select the code used and in Barcode->Value you can put a formula/field/constant for the barcode value.

[image]

As for the red cross lines, my guess is that your controls are overlapping. Check that your controls are not placed on top of each other in the report designer. Also if the barcode is too long to fit in the control size it will display red cross. Try making the control wider or reducing `BarWidth` property to make it fit in the picture control container.
[image]